# Download image from url, image is not opening

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to **download image** from *Google Drive*, but the image is not opening for some reason.

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36";
webClient.DownloadFile(url, @"path_to_download.png");
```

The URL looks like https://drive.google.com/file/d/1231231313+yDnEx7upHEsM4ozjh/view from this URL I take the image source. It looks like https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/drive-viewer/ASAdd1d123sT1QX_ZYlcoHMTeDBeUJaNnwxqjJzFgC8e24i1HOylgu2MnqzO9iNb41exySXsp2sJWA=w1106-h772 and after that, I run the code upper. Everything works, but I cannot open the image.

Comment: Google Drive may use additional auth tokens while downloading something from the second url you mentioned, You can use Dev-Console/Network tab and see what headers does that request have and add them to your code,Additionally there is already official [google drive api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads) you can use